# How to make a dynamic interval in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

**list.component.html**

```
  <nz-select nzShowSearch nzPlaceHolder="Select a interval" [(ngModel)]="selectIntervalValueStr" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange()" style="width:100%">
        <nz-option nzLabel="5 minutes" nzValue="1000"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzLabel="10 minutes" nzValue="5000"></nz-option>
        <nz-option nzLabel="15 minutes" nzValue="10000"></nz-option>
      </nz-select>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
infLoop: any;
  selectIntervalValueStr: any;
  selectIntervalValue: number = 300000;



  onSelectChange() {
    this.selectIntervalValue = +this.selectIntervalValueStr;
  }

  chartIntervalFunction() {


 if (this.infLoop != null || this.infLoop != undefined) {
  clearInterval(this.infLoop);
}

this.infLoop = setInterval(() => {
  this.getRoomList();
  console.log(this.selectIntervalValue);
}, this.selectIntervalValue);

  }
```

How to make a dynamic interval.
using select option where there's an item which is 5 minutes equivalent into `300000` , 10 minutes equivalent into `600000` and 15 minutes equivalent into `900000`.

on my side I tried to console the `this.selectIntervalValue` inside the chartIntervalFunction, yes It gets the value, but when I applied it in the `setInterval` it doesn't work. it run automatically none stop running

Comment: Try to return the value from `setInterval()` method instead of initialization. `this` might behaving differently in this method

Comment: @JaydipJadhav wdym sir?

Comment: You will need to save the return value of [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp) and use `clearInterval` to stop the old timer.

Comment: @fredrik `let refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
          this.getRoomList();
        }, 600000);
        clearInterval(refreshInterval);`?

Comment: @fredrik is it correct ??

Comment: Yes, you need to clear the interval you had set previously by assigning to a variable, have a look at my answer =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from [W3Schools Window setInterval():](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

You are essentially creating an infinite loop that is invoked at specific intervals. You can't just dynamically change the interval count with a property. You have to clear the infinite loop you had previously created and create a new `setInterval()`

Also, I will refrain from using `setInterval()` as the binded event function's name. Cause it is ambiguous with Window's `setInterval(function)`. Something like `onSelectChange()` makes for better readability.

```js
infLoop;
selectIntervalValueStr;
selectIntervalValue: number = 300000; //300_000 is default if you set here

onSelectChange(){
   this.selectIntervalValue = +this.selectIntervalValueStr; //convert to number with + symbol, alternatively parseInt(this.selectIntervalValueStr) should also work.
}

chartIntervalFunction() {
   if(this.infLoop != null || this.infLoop != undefined){
      clearInterval(this.infLoop);
   }

   this.infLoop = setInterval(() => {
      this.getRoomList();
      console.log(this.selectIntervalValue);
   }, this.selectIntervalValue);
}
```

You need to change your html also:

```html
<nz-select ... [(ngModel)]="selectIntervalValueStr" (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange()" ...>
```

Comment: Type 'string' is not comparable to type 'number'

Comment: Ah, because you're using the same class property in your switch case and binded with `<nz-select>`. On second read, your switch statement isn't really necessary also since it's just converting a string to number which you can easily do with javascript/typescript.

Comment: ERROR TypeError: _co.setInterval is not a function

Comment: you didn't change your `(ngModelChange)="setInterval()"` to `(ngModelChange)="onSelectChange()"`

Comment: Because you changed your `nzValue` from 300000 to 1000? 1000ms is 1s. Of course the loop will execute every 1s.

Comment: I change the value of my 5mins which is 1second it should display the console at 1 second right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200883/discussion-between-abc-and-terahertz).